# UI Suggestion for switching apps

Tags: web, toggle, app

Scenario : Just like in google switching apps from the top right corner cube button, where the user can quickly navigate to gmail, gdrive etc. I have kept the switching of app on the left side with a down arrow. Is the down arrow a good approach for letting the users know that from there the apps can be switched?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> Is the down arrow a good approach for letting the users know that from
>   there the apps can be switched?

**No.**

**You need an icon to hide Apps under it**; [**icon finder**](https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=apps) is suggesting similar to Google or MS Outlook type App Icons:

---

Users have formed a specific mental model with dropdown arrows, they will think that the content hidden under Platform dropdown will be related to Platform service. **They won't expect some another app or service to be hidden under it**.

But, the label of that dropdown arrow can be helpful: **More Apps**

Comment: But in the same top bar, we also have other 4 btns like search, user profile, notifications and requests. So when in responsive mode, all the icons come together and doesnt look good.

Comment: @DivyanshPatel Place them on top with proper space - adjust the layout differently for different screens so that it doesn't appear cluttered. See how Google does it for small screens.